# How to make TSLint to throw a warning if file names are not lowercase?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an angular.io project using `ng new`. I have already set `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` to true in tsconfig.json. I would like to make sure that developers in my team get a warning when they are using upper-case in the new filenames they create.

How can I do this?

Comment: In a project I'm working on we added this as a commit hook from branch to develop/trunk. Would likely get caught in a code-review before getting that far, but it's still helpful to make sure.

Comment: You can write custom rule https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/